# Invalid parameter number for PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Next code gives me an error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `date_install`, `date_ping`, `cc`, `uv`, `pid`, `pv`, `aff_id`, `sub_id`, `channel`, `cid`, `os`, `av`, `db`) VALUES (:id, :date_install, now(), :country, :updaterVersion, :productId, :productVersion, :affiliateId, :subId, :channel, :commandId, :os, :av, :defaultBrowser) "
     . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date_install` = :date_install, `date_ping` = now(), `cc` = :country, `uv` = :updaterVersion, `pid` = :productId, `pv` = :productVersion, `aff_id` = :affiliateId, `sub_id` = :subId, `channel` = :channel, `cid` = :commandId, `os` = :os, `av` = :av, `db` = :defaultBrowser ";

$statement = $database->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":id", $user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":date_install", $user->date_install, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":country", $user->cc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":updaterVersion", $user->uv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":productId", $user->pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":productVersion", $user->pv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":affiliateId", $user->aff_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":subId", $user->sub_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":channel", $user->channel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":commandId", $user->cid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":os", $user->os, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":av", $user->av, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":defaultBrowser", $user->db, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();
```

I have no idea what is wrong and if I copy/paste SQL into console and replace all values manually everything works. Also if I comment out part `ON DUPLICATE KEY...`, also works.

Comment: Where's a value for `date_ping`?

Comment: That's an awful lot of values to update when it already exists - I'm mildly worried about your data integrity!

Comment: @HankyPanky it's there as `now()`

Comment: @RobbieAverill Sometimes we get a request with same key and in that case values must be updated to the sent one values.

Comment: what is your database side set to for id, is it auto increment?

Comment: id is type varchar(255) and its value is sent in request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [emulation mode is turned off](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) for your PDO instance, you won't be able to use the same placeholder name more than once in the query.

Besides, for the ON DUPLICATE it is not necessary either, as you can always use the `VALUES` operator that will take the value from the VALUES clause:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date_install` = VALUES(date_install), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO Doesn't allow repetition of variable names. Your ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE should have it's own variable names. Which also means you have to assign your variables 2 times. This is a sad limitation :(.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the same parameter names twice, you must set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute to `true`:

```sql
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```